# Ideas to improve chess books usability in the XXI century

Tags: books

I enjoy reading a book of chess on the outside, with my iPhone (and Stockfish) to explore situations. However, I spend too many time setting up the board manually. So here's a crazy idea (patent-free): **Encode board positions (FEN) in QR-Codes!** Example:

[image: QR-Encoded FEN]

What other simple ideas could improve the usability of current (printed) books?

Comment: Hi Hugo, I closed this question because right now it's soliciting opinions as opposed to asking a question that can be answered.  I think this is a great topic (and new technology like e-readers can vastly improve chess books), so I hope that you reformulate the question so that it can be answered.  For more information, you can see this blog post: [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: Awesome idea, by the way.

Comment: @Andrew: I tried to improve the question so it could better fit the rules.

Answer (score 4):

I've long felt that scripting short systems of moves in their chess notation would be very helpful as a teaching tool as well.  There are many, many projects out there that can replay a set of instructions, and it would make it much easier to not only show how to set up some of the basic openings, but also explore their ramifications in response to different positions.